# UICollectionView - random cells are selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a Horizontal UICollectionView like the horizontal Calender in iOS.
Paging is enabled but not allowsMultipleSelection.

```
self.allowsMultipleSelection = false
self.isPagingEnabled = true
```

There are only 5 cells per page.

```
 let cellSize =    CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 5 , height: 60)
```

CollectionView's height is also 60.

**didSelectItemAt** change background color to **.red** and **didDeselectItem** resets it to **.white**.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    if let cell = cell {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    if let cell = cell {
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

The collection view has multiple sections and rows. If I select a cell in the first visible page and scroll, random cells are selected in the next visible pages. That is to say random cells are red in the next pages. I do not want this to be so. I want to select/change color of cells manually.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Cells are reused from a recycled ones, you need somehow to persist the state of every cell and assign the value in cellForRow

Comment: Can you show your cellForRowAt method ?

Comment: You need to have to hold your selected indexes and render it accordingly in `cellForRow`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that UICollectionView has embedded reusing mechanism, so you should deselect your cells in the method "prepareToReuse" directly inside the cell class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a class-level variable, say `index`

```
var index = -1
```

As you have said that multiple selections are not allowed so the following will do the job for you

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath.item
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    if let cell = cell {
        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item == index ? .red :  .white
    }
}
```

Whenever user tap on any cell we save the position in `index` variable and then call the reloadData() to notify collectionView about the change
In `cellForRowAt`  we check if the current cell us selected we set the color to red otherwise white

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to preserve **multiple selection**, you have to remember your selected ones in an array since it would get lost if a cell gets recycled and reused. For that use something like a [IndexPath] type). If one selected cell is enough, you could use a non-array version of below code.

```
var selectedItems: [IndexPath] = []
```

Then, do your recoloring in your cell's `cellForItemAt(:)`:

```
cell.backgroundColor = selectedItems.contains(indexPath) ? .red : .white
```

Your `didSelectItemAt` delegate function should look like:

```
if !selectedItems.contains(indexPath) { selectedItems.append(indexPath)}

collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = .red
```

and your `didDeselectItemAt` delegate function:

```
if let index = selectedItems.firstIndex(of: indexPath) { selectedItems.remove(at: index) }

collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = .white
```

This should actually work. Let me know if we have to do adjustments.